# How extract part of the video with EMGU

Tags: c#, emgucv

I am trying to create small app in C# that will load a video file, that for example has 600 frames. I want to display frames and to set start frame (for example frame number 100) and end frame (for example frame number 500) and the output of the application should be new video from start point to end point. I am a newbie to EMGU so anyone help me achieve this.

I am planning to create simple UI that will enable user to move start marker (regarding start frame position) as well as end marker (regarding end frame position).

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the frames you want to keep and use [VideoWriter](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.4.2/document/html/3fb90645-ecc4-0c4e-b238-6d0ca38f4ebc.htm) and its method [WriteFrame()](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.4.2/document/html/fc05f588-4769-c79d-ef5b-cfe9926701ea.htm) to write them to a video.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing.  I just found this:  http://splicer.codeplex.com/

Does that work for you?

Here is another source:  http://blog.kaltura.org/announcing-kalturas-new-clipping-application